# Navbar Overlaps Carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem.

I made a change on a website of mine, I wanted to incorporate a full-width carousel on my website. Instead of a jumbotron.
The problem is my navbar is overlapping the jumbotron area, the caption and everything.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="nav-area">
    <div class="container"> <!-- Start Container -->

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">

                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>

                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="dentalclean logo" src="images/logo_2x.png">
                  </a>

                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Pagina Inicial <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li> -->

                  </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->


              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>

        </div> <!-- End Container -->
</div>

<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
<div class="hero-section"> <!-- Start Hero Section -->

<div id="slider_dentalclean" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider_dentalclean" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider_dentalclean" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#slider_dentalclean" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img alt="Dentista Leiria" src="images/hero-img.png">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                    <p>LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Second slide" src="images/hero-img.png">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img alt="Third slide" src="images/hero-img.png">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I apologize for the lack of organization.

I'm using sass and bootstrap by the way.

Here is the resulting problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bigm6291gmwgcf6/Screenshot%202015-04-06%2018.46.43.png?dl=0

Thank you very much, I searched for all the answers here, but I couldn't find one that works.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yjbjvtx2/

CSS:

```
    .nav-area{
      position:absolute;
      top: 0;

   }

    #slider_dentalclean{
      margin-top: 0;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

I have found the exact thing I want in my website: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

But I don't understand how they make the carousel caption not go behind the navbar.

Comment: This really needs to be in a fiddle with the extra CSS. Why do you have a -73px margin on the main div? It looks like it would be fixed if you set that to 0 or something positive.

Comment: Will put on fiddle right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a top margin to your .hero-section?

```
.hero-section{
   margin-top:5em;
```

}

Or remove the negative margin on the #slider_dentalclean?

```
#slider_dentalclean{
  /*margin-top: -73px;*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I pulled in the **carousel.CSS** from the example you mentioned. Make sure you are including the bootstrap.js too. I updated the fiddle below with these two files included and put one of your slides in the template.

I am not 100% sure it works as you expect, as I cannot see dropbox files, so your image doesn't show up. Maybe add one to imgr or substitite a demo image from google or getty.

https://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/o8zqyt06/ **UPDATED**

Comment: I want for the nav to be on top of the image.  Like I had before https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzjuikts8b8z8um/Screenshot%202015-04-06%2019.26.38.png?dl=0   ... but instead of static I want it to be a slider.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the entire fiddle, I'm behind a firewall that blocks dropbox

Comment: Oh ok, np. I have updated the question, and I have posted the exact thing I want on my website. All looks well on big screens , but when you resize to a small size , the carousel caption starts to up , behind the nav and it even partially disappears from the page.

Comment: @user3870894 I updated my answer, this should give you a good start to build on

Comment: I have included the js, the problem , and you have the same problem in your fiddle, is that when you scale down the window , the caption goes behind the navbar. Also, the design you have on your fiddle is different than in mine, I want the navbar to be on top of the carousel (check my fiddle).

Comment: @user3870894 I updated my fiddle to reflect your request; Your overwrite of the .hero-section p is what is causing the overlap.

Comment: Your fiddle has the same problem. if you shrink the window (in width) , you'll see that the text and carousel start hiding behind the navbar.